# is there any disadvantage or limitations of setting maximum session out time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

In asp.net, the default session time out is 20 minutes. Suppose if i am changing the session time out period to 2 hours or greater than of its, then will it cause any performance issue on server side?

I would like to know Is there any limitations or disadvantages of using maximum session out time in asp.net?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sessions are **maintained on server for each user**. Increase in session time out will prevent the Server from releasing memory allocated to inactive session.

> I would like to know Is there any limitations or disadvantages of
>   using maximum session out time in asp.net?

[HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The Timeout property cannot be set to a value greater than 525,600
>   minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes.

**Disadvantage:**
You will have performance issues if you have large number of users and with increase in session timeout, your inactive sessions will remain in Web server memory which may cause application pool to recycle, which would result in loosing all sessions for all users.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, added now :)

Comment: Any ballpark figures on wht a 'large number of users' is? How much memory roughly would - say - storing a few Guid's in the session for each user user?

Answer (score 1):

If you are you using IIS6 or greater then depending on your Application Pool settings it may affect how frequently the w3wp process is recycled. When the app pool is recycled your sessions will be lost unless you use [out-of-process session state management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225449%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or sql as a session state host.

If you increase the timeout to two hours individual users wont lose their session as often, but it increases the odds that all users browsing the site will occasionally get logged off when the process is recycled.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the session time means that a web page left idle is less likely to time out (such as if the user goes to lunch leaving the web page open). However, this takes up more server resources, since, as Habib says, the server must store the user information during this time.

It can also be is a security risk. If the user closes the web page rather than logs out, it increases the window for a [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.

The best thing to do is understand how your users use the web page. If pages must be kept open for long periods, look at a periodic callback or refresh for the page. Alternatively, if the site is security sensitive, consider logging the user out automatically after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Take in consideration that if your trying to raise the timeout value in a **shared hosting environment** you will fail as they block you from this by set that value in the `machine.config` file and hat takes precedent, you will need to use **SQL Session** 's for that and you will be free to change that timeout time as you please.

They also normally restart the AppPool every often to unblock any malicious or bad code that could block other websites, and every time the AppPool restart, here goes all your sessions (not if you use SQL Sessions instead, of course)...

In the other hand, if your **hosting the web application yourself**, aside of the size in memory (remember that Im assuming that you are saying **user sessions** and as the name says, are per user, per application you would use Application Sessions). If you consider this memory increase, nothing, not even performance would be diminish.